# Compare $-2$ and $2-\sqrt{3}$

Tags: inequality

I am trying to solve: $$x^2+\sqrt{3}x+2\sqrt{3}-4 < 0$$
Let us solve $x^2+\sqrt{3}x+2\sqrt{3}-4=0$. We get that $D=(4-\sqrt{3})^2$ and $x_{1,2}=-2;2-\sqrt{3}$. We can say $2-\sqrt{3}>-2$, but which is the best way to write it and show it? Are there any general methods? I don't want to use the approximate value of $\sqrt{3}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $3<4$, $\sqrt3<\sqrt4=2$. So, $2-\sqrt3>0$. Now, since $-2<0$…

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the inequality as $$4>\sqrt 3.$$ That is now so obvious, since if $4>3,$ then $\sqrt 4>\sqrt 3.$ But Since $4>\sqrt 4=2,$ then the original inequality follows by transitivity.

Answer (score 1):

We can start from showing that $2>\sqrt{3}$. This is simple because squaring we have $4>3$, so $$2>\sqrt{3}$$
From here, we have that: $2-\sqrt{3}>0$. And so, because $-2<0$, we have:
$$-2<2-\sqrt{3}$$

Answer (score 1):

We want to solve 
$$
x^2 + \sqrt{3} x + 2\sqrt{3} - 4 < 0.
$$
We know that the LHS is a polynomial of 2nd order and thus that the LHS has at most two zeros. As you write these are
$$x \in \{ -2, 2 - \sqrt{3}\}$$
This means that we can factorize our polynomial as 
$$
x^2 + \sqrt{3} x + 2\sqrt{3} - 4 = (x+2)(x-2+\sqrt{3})
$$
We can now find the values of $x$ such that
$$
(x+2)(x-2+\sqrt{3}) < 0
$$
By standard rules of multiplication this holds when

- $(x+2)< 0$ and $(x-2+\sqrt{3}) > 0$
- $(x+2)> 0$ and $(x-2+\sqrt{3}) < 0$

We simplify these to

- $x<-2$ and $x > 2-\sqrt{3}$
- $x>-2$ and $x<2-\sqrt{3}$

As $-2 < 2-\sqrt{3}$ it is impossible to satisfy the requirements of the first scenario and we are left with the single interval $x>-2$ and $x < 2-\sqrt{3}$. We conclude that 
$$
x^2 + \sqrt{3} x + 2\sqrt{3} - 4 < 0.
$$
if $x\in (-2, 2-\sqrt{3})$.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2+\sqrt{3}x+2(\sqrt{3}-2)$

$=x^2+(\sqrt{3}-2)x+2x+2(\sqrt{3}-2)$

$=(x+2)(x+(\sqrt{3}-2))$

So what you're solving is:

$(x+2)(x+(\sqrt{3}-2)) \lt 0$

And the interval pops out nicely!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Back up a bit and it will become obvious which of the two roots is the lesser. As I’m sure you know, by the quadratic formula, the roots of $ax^2+bx+c=0$ are $${-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}\over2a}.$$ This expression says that the two roots are found by adding and subtracting the same nonnegative number to/from $-\frac b{2a}$. Clearly, the value that you get by *subtracting* is going to be less than (or equal to) the one that you get by adding, so simply keep track of which is which as you solve the equation.